# Typescript/Angular: Object is not Assignable to type

Tags: angular, typescript

so I'm using ngx-charts for my project and currently I'm stuck in a seemingly dull error on my end of the typescript code. I have tested the following data and it is working as expected:

```
export var productSalesMulti = [
{
  name: 'Cotação',
  series: [
    {
      name: '0',
      value: 10,
    },
    {
      name: '1',
      value: 20,
    },
    {
      name: '2',
      value: 30,
    },
    {
      name: '3',
      value: 20,
    },
    {
      name: '4',
      value: 40,
    },
    {
      name: '5',
      value: 30,
    },
    {
      name: '6',
      value: 10,
    },
    {
      name: '7',
      value: 15,
    },
    {
      name: '8',
      value: 35,
    },
    {
      name: '9',
      value: 50,
    },
    {
      name: '10',
      value: 35,
    },
    {
      name: '11',
      value: 40,
    }
  ]

}]
```

The input of my component is looking like: [image]

But I`m getting the following error:

Error: src/app/shared/components/grafico-ibovespa/grafico-ibovespa.component.ts:40:5 - error TS2322: Type '{ name: string; series: { name: string; value: number; }[]; }[]' is not assignable to type '[{ name: String; series: [{ name: String; value: number; }]; }]'.
Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.

40     this.ibovespaGraphData = productSalesMulti;

So I know that my input declaration is wrong, but I'm seeing where the problem is. I know I could just write: @Input() ibovespaGraphData : any[] and it would work, but for sake of readability I would rather not to. Thank you in advance for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrongly added type to `ibovespaGraphData` it is considered as value  in your code and type infered different. It should be like below

```
ibovespaGraphData : Array<{
  name: string;
  series: Array<{
    name: string;
    value: number;
  }>
}>
```

or like this

```
ibovespaGraphData  : {
  name: string;
  series: {
    name: string;
    value: number;
  }[]
}[]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I made this changes and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, should work-

```
@Input('dadosIbovespaGrafico') IbovespaGraphData: {
  name: string;
  series: {
    name: string;
    value: number;
  }[]
}[]
```